# Meaning of the word "else"

Tags: meaning

> "If anyone tells you that a certain person speaks ill of you, do not
>   make excuses about what is said of you but answer, ‘He was ignorant of
>   my other faults, else he would have not mentioned these alone.'" –
>   Epictetus

What does the word "else" mean? I think it means "otherwise". Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Else used as shown is a conjunction, meaning 'otherwise'. It is common in, but not exclusive to, British English. Examples:

- We must repair the walls, else the roof will collapse.
- Hurry, else you will be late.

Comment: This is not uncommon in American English, at least in formal writing.  Although it may be true that the British are more often formal than we are.

Comment: It's more often rendered in AE as "or else" ...

Comment: Else meaning 'otherwise' is not particularly 'formal' in British English, and is common in Northern regional speech, where 'otherwise would be heard as stiff and formal.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is old fashioned, probably because you are reading a translation that was made in the ninteenth or early twentieth century. A modern writer of American English would likely write the two words **or else** instead of the one word **else**. **Otherwise** would be a good substitute, but again **or otherwise** would likely be more common.

One of the defects of the English lexicon is that there is no universally accepted way to distinguish between what mathematicians call the inclusive **or** and the exclusive **or**. The phrase **A or B** means A alone or B alone or both A and B: **or** alone is lexically inclusive (although logic may indicate that the meaning is exclusive). It is equivalent to the Latin **vel**. Latin had the form **aut A aut B** to mark the exclusive **or**: A or B but not both.

**A else B** is one old fashioned way to form an exclusive **or**. I prefer **either A or else B**, but the only way to be sure that every English speaker will grasp that you mean an exclusive **or** is to exclude the possibility of both A and B explicitly. The usage of **else** in your example to mean an exclusive **or** unfortunately did not catch on.

Comment: -1 for "one of the defects etc etc".  There's  a way to express the idea, though perhaps not in a single word.

Comment: "There is a way to express the idea." There is, and I explained how to do so. "Though **perhaps** not in a single word" suggests that you have at least one single word to propose as a candidate. It would help were you to disclose it. Your "etc, etc" is a neat rhetorical trick to leave out the key word in what I actually wrote, namely **lexicon.** If you are unable to come up with the single word that denotes an exclusive **or** in English, then your objection seems frivolous. If you can do so, then I shall thank you sincerely and edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: It wasn't a rhetorical trick. I just didn't want to type out the full sentence. My objection relates to your allegation that the "English lexicon" is defective, for a natural language cannot be tarred in that way. Only a formal language can be. Natural languages rely upon context in ways that formal languages do not. In context, English can express both concepts in ways that are universally understood by humans, even if they fail to satisfy a logician's sense of the unambiguous and "do not compute".

Comment: You are of course entitled to your normative opinion that every natural language should be deemed flawless. But I still think it is a rhetorical trick to fail to quote the word that is essential to the argument being disputed, particularly when the fact behind the argument is evaded with a "perhaps."

Comment: And you're welcome to your opinion that the English lexicon is "defective".